# Unable to load Json.NET dll Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have an [Indie license](https://store.xamarin.com/) for Xamarin so that I can develop apps for iPhone/iPad in my most proficient programming language, C#.  With this license I can't use the `Visual Studio` plugin from Xamarin.  I still prefer `Visual Studio` to `Xamarin Studio`, so I still develop on `Visual Studio` whatever code that does not need `MonoTouch` references and then just manually copy the dll into `Xamarin Studio`.

I have one assembly, .Net framework 4.5, that gets the following error message when I try to debug my app:

> Loaded assembly: /Users/EdGriMac/Dropbox/Quiz/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   [External]
>   2013-09-23 20:30:38.021 Exam936[2228:c07] Could not load 'Newtonsoft.Json' for registration:
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
>     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:351
>     at MonoTouch.Registrar.OldDynamicRegistrar.RegisterAssembly
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/OldDynamicRegistrar.cs:67
>   2013-09-23 20:30:38.023 Exam936[2228:c07] This could be due to an outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location:
>   /Users/EdGriMac/Dropbox/Quiz/Newtonsoft.Json.dll

My tries:

1. The first thing that springs to mind is that `NewtonSoft.Json` can't be used with MonoTouch, but I don't know how to find out.  Is there a way to find out for sure if a 3rd party dll can be used?
2. My second idea was that an older or newer version of `NewtonSoft.Json` could be used by another assembly.  This is not a large project, however, and the only other assembly I have that uses `Json` is [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), but I don't think that uses `NewtonSoft.Json`.  I looked at the web pages for their GitHub page, but was unable to find a reference.
3. I googled a bit and found [this post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3580/google-app-analytics-support-in-monotouch) saying that (a bit down) `MonoTouch.Registrar.OldDynamicRegistrar.RegisterAssembly` indicates that (quote:) `I can't build the app using the build flags --registrar:olddynamic. If I remove that, it now works, I can now link and it appears to be working..`  This is probably a setting in `Visual Studio` you can adjust when you have a `Business license`.  I don't know how to build without these flags.

Is what I am trying to do possible?  If yes, what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the Json.Net version that is available from the Xamarin Component store. it just works.

Comment: Scanning this assembly using http://scan.xamarin.com/ as you suggested on my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980512/how-to-find-out-if-assembly-can-be-used-by-monotouch/18980843#18980843) showed me that `NewtonSoft.Json` is only 90% compatible.  I will try your alternative later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Json.NET version from Xamarin component store (http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/) works fine. And it installs directly from within `Xamarin Studio`

Comment: I don't quite understand why, but, as you say, it just works.

Comment: because someone took the time to adapt it so it is compatible with the .NET profile available in monoTouch.

Comment: This is not longer the case as of 5.1 (build 479)