# How to find out if assembly can be used by MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

If you create an assembly in `Visual Studio`, build it and then use the built `.dll` as a reference in `Xamarin Studio`, how can you find out if the assembly can be used except by running it?  How do you know if a 3rd party .Net assembly can run on `MonoTouch`?

I just asked [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978932/unable-to-load-dll-xamarin-studio) that was related, but wanted to see if this could be answered by itself (otherwise it would drown and go unnoticed in the the other question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scan it on http://scan.xamarin.com/. It'll give you the information you need.